# Invertibility of infinite-dimensional matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-analysis, infinite-matrices

I have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ whose columns are linearly independent. Hence, $M$ is invertible.

How to extend this conclusion to the case where $n$ is infinite?

Specifically, given that $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$ satisfy that 
\begin{align}
y = M x.
\end{align}

What conditions do I need to conclude that $M$ is a bounded invertible linear operator?

p.s. If $n$ is finite, it seems that the conclusion hold when $M$ is of full rank and with bounded matrix norm. If $n$ is infinite, what arguments can I use?

Comment: How do you extend your definitions to that case, and how infinite is $n$? Assuming $n=\Bbb N$, the product of two such matrices is still not always well-defined, take for instance the matrix whose entries are all $1$ and multiply it with itself. With multiplication somewhat undefined, I just feel a little uneasy about the term "invertible".

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Thanks for your comments. I update my question. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In my problem, the matrix $M$ has full rank and bounded norm for any finite $n$.  I wonder how to extend this property to the case $n\rightarrow\infty$. Could you please provide any hint on this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the "infinite matrix" representation of a linear operator is not that popular, especially in non-Hilbert contexts. There are many technicalities to address, as Jesko rightfully points out. Anyway, I remember that I have seen some information on this point of view on the book "Basic operator theory" of Gohberg and Goldberg.

Answer (score 3):

A bounded linear map $T:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces $X,Y$ is invertible---in the sense that there exists a bounded inverse---[if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/759630) ${}^1$ $T$ is bounded from below and its image is dense in $Y$. Actually if a linear map is bounded from below then in particular [it is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2686907) so we can strengthen this criterion:

> A linear map $T:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces $X,Y$ is invertible if $T$ is bounded from below and its image is dense in $Y$.

Now if $X,Y$ even have a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) so $T$ can be identified with a countably infinite matrix $M_T$ (containing the corresponding basis expansion coefficients) then this can, at least partially, be translated to the information given by $M_T$: the image of $T$ is dense if and only if the columns of $M_T$ span a dense subset of $Y$, which is the best generalization of "the columns have to be linearly independent" I can think of.

Roughly speaking boundedness from below ensures injectivity and density of the image handles surjectivity. Be aware that boundedness from below also guarantees boundedness of $T$ as well as $T^{-1}$, something not present in usual linear algebra as [every linear map between finite-dimensional spaces is automatically bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112985).

To conclude lets give an example which shows that boundedness and linear independence of columns is not sufficient beyond finite dimensions: let $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ be the Hilbert space of all square-summable sequences with standard basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, $e_n=(\delta_{jn})_{j\in\mathbb N}$ and consider the right shift $T:\ell^2\to\ell^2$, $e_n\mapsto e_{n+1}$. This operator is an isometry ($\|Tx\|=\|x\|$, thus bounded: $\|T\|=1$) and the corresponding matrix in this basis is of the form
$$
M_T=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0&\cdots\\1&0&0&0&\cdots\\0&1&0&0&\cdots\\0&0&1&0&\cdots\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots \end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
The columns are linearly independent (even orthonormal)---thus $T$ is *injective* which also reflects in boundedness from below (holds because $T$ is isometry). However the span of the columns is not dense as $e_1\not\in\overline{\operatorname{im}(T)}$ so surjectivity fails. While in finite-dimensions, the rank-nullity theorem saves you from such situations, as there "no kernel" means "full image", in infinite-dimensions you lucked out.

---

<sub>${}^1$: The linked math.SE-question asks about the case where $X,Y$ are Hilbert spaces, but the proof at no point uses the existence of an inner product (just that $X,Y$ are complete normed spaces) so the result holds for arbitrary Banach spaces.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to interpret your question. I can think of two ways:

(1) Saying a matrix $M$ is invertible is equivalent (or by definition, depending on your definition) to saying that there exists a matrix $M'$ such that $MM'=I$ and $M'M=I$, where $I$ is the diagonal matrix with only $1$'s. It's possible to define the multiplication of infinite dimensional matrices analogously to the finite case (although the sums may not converge), and we can also define $I$. Therefore, we can say that an infinite-dimensional matrix is invertible if there exists $M'$ such that $MM'$ and $M'M$ are well-defined, and if they both are equal to $I$.

(2) If you want to stick to the idea of linearly independent vectors, there exist infinite-dimensional vector spaces, and the concept of linear independence still exists. For example, $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, the vector space of real-valued sequences, is a vector space, with the zero vector $(0,0,0,\ldots)$ and term-wise sum. We can see that the vectors $a_n=(0,\ldots,0,1,1,\ldots)$, which are $0$ up to the $n^\text{th}$ term and $1$ afterwards, are linearly independent. Therefore, the infinite-dimensional matrix $M$ whose $n^\text{th}$ column is exactly $a_n$ has linearly independent columns, and so we can consider $M$ to be invertible.

I'm not sure if these concepts are equivalent, and in general infinite-dimensional matrices aren't the best way to study infinite-dimensional vector spaces, but I hope I gave you some ideas on what it might entail :)

Comment: Thanks. Your comments help a lot. As for the example in Item (2), I wonder how can you conclude M is invertible? Is there any reference on this? What I am actually interested in is how to prove that the infinite-dimensional M is a bounded invertible operator. I edit the question. Do you have any clue on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge of infinite-dimensional operators is quite limited, so I don't know of any references. Maybe this question will help, at least for invertibility? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339436/show-that-the-operator-is-invertible

Comment: Thanks. I will check :).

Answer (score 0):

Extending one aspect of @IsaacRen's answer:

- If the matrix $M$ is lower triangular, and its inverse $M'$ as well (and $M \cdot M'=I$ ) then it is easier to extend this to the case of infinite size.
  For instance the lower triangular Pascal-/Binomial-matrix -whether finite or infinite- is invertible this way. *(Note, I've read one time that the inverse in the infinite case should be named "reciprocal" instead, but don't have the reference at hand, maybe it is also referenced in wikipedia)*

And more:

- For the case of infinite size they have introduced the terms "row-finite" and "column-finite" of which the lower and the upper triangular matrices are subcases.
- There are also interesting special cases: the matrix of the Stirling-numbers 2nd kind $S2$ and that of the Stirling-numbers 1st kind are "reciprocals" of each other, such that $S1 \cdot S2 = S2 \cdot S1 = I$ . But there are then non-triangular variants of $S1_k$ possible such that still $S1_K \cdot S2 =I$.
- For the analysis, whether a square infinite matrix is invertible, I've always used the $LDU$ -decomposition where $ M = L \cdot D \cdot U$ from where $L$ is lower triangular, $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is upper triangular. Then if all three new matrices are invertible, then one can proceed and look, based on the analytic description of the entries of $L^{-1},D^{-1},U^{-1}$ , whether all occuring single dotproducts of $(U^{-1} \cdot D^{-1}) \cdot L^{-1}$ are convergent or at least "summable" (in the sense of summation of divergent series).

  For instance, the infinite squarematrix 
  $$ V = \small \begin{bmatrix}
    1&0&0&0&\cdots \\
    1&1&1&1&\cdots \\
    1&2&4&8&\cdots \\
    1&3&9&27&\cdots \\
    \vdots \end{bmatrix}
  $$
  is decomposable in LDU-components, and all three components are invertible, but the reverse product of the inverted components is divergent in each dotproduct of rows with columns.
- About a problem-consideration: when dotproducts $U^{-1} \cdot D^{-1} \cdot L^{-1}$ become divergent, you may be interested in [this answer of mine in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89839/1714).

Curiosity:

- as a surprising finding I had even a harmless looking matrix $M$ of infinite size, and the analysis in the above LDU-sense, using summation-procedures for the row-column-dotproducts in $(U^{-1} \cdot D^{-1}) \cdot L^{-1}$ gave ***all*** zero, so the inverse of $M$ should be the ZERO-matrix! *(see [essay at my homepage](http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/InverseNullmatrix.pdf) and proof in [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104370/an-infinite-set-of-identities-using-stirling-numbers-1st-kind-are-they-all-zer))* Such unexpectable effects are only possible with infinite matrices...